# crankshaft rotation R6

Tags: engine, motorcycle, yamaha

I am performing a valve adjustment, I have been reading the yamaha r6 workshop manual, and it tells me to rotate the crankshaft counterclockwise, by doing this I hear gear sounds that I did not like, and by turning the crankshaft clockwise it does not.

Is there any reason to reverse the crankshaft? All the motorcycle engines I have seen rotated clockwise.

I'm a little scared from the sound it made, but I've followed what the manual said

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks, nothing has happened, which I do not understand what is the purpose of turning in reverse.